# How can I GAE (Eclipse IDE) to kill previous instance of test server when I start debugging?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, process, debugging, kill

GAE Eclipse IDE launches test server instance when I start debugging.
But the test server instance does not killed when I restart the debugging after some code modified. This annoying. I have to kill previous instance manually on each time before new instance launched because previous instance holds port.

How can I make the IDE kill previous instance when I launch new instance of current project?

Answer (score 2):

Try executing the goal `gae:stop` to stop debugging.